# Install Pillow on 3.3 when 2.7 is also installed(Linux)

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library

I have both Python 2.7 and 3.3 installed on my system.  I'm trying to hopefully write everything for 3.3.  I've run into a snag.  I need to install Pillow on 3.3 so I can use Images.  How do I get it to install on 3.3.  If I try

```
pip install Pillow
```

It comes up and says 'Requirement already satisfied(use --upgrade to upgrade): Pillow in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'

How do I get Pillow to install on 3.3, since that is where I need it?

I ran through the rest of the install(setuptools and prerequisites).  Not sure where they installed.  I did use the python3-setuptools for the initial install attempt.  I don't know if that helped to control the flow of the prerequisites to 3.3 or not.

This is on a Linux system.

Comment: usualy if you are on linux, pip for 3.3 will be pip-3.3 or something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 2.7 and 3.3 have their own separate site-packages locations.

And, just as they have their own separate executables (usually `python` and `python2.7` for 2.7, and `python3` and `python3.3` for 3.3), when you install `pip` for each one, they'll each have their own `pip` scripts (usually `pip`, `pip2`, and `pip2.7` vs. `pip3` and `pip3.3`).

So, just do this:

```
pip3.3 install Pillow
```

---

As a side note, if you use virtual environments, either via the third-party [`virtualenv`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) package or the stdlib [`venv`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) package (3.3+ only, and really not worth using until 3.4), this problem goes away: when you're inside a virtual environment, it's either a 2.7 environment or a 3.3 environment, and it's as if nothing else exists.

---

The basic design is explained in [PEP 394](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/). How `pip` fits into that design is explained in… as far as I know, docs that haven't been written yet, but will hopefully be part of Python 3.4.0 and/or pip 1.5.something.

Older versions of `pip` (I believe before 1.5.0) would use `pip` and `pip-2.7` vs. `pip` and `pip-3.3`, which obviously leads to a bit of confusion.

And some distros have their own `python-pip` packages that do things differently. And then there's Arch, where `python` actually means 3.2. And so on.

But the basic idea is that when you have Python X.Y and V.W side by side, there will be some way to differentiate explicitly.

Comment: may also be pip-3.3 depends on distro

Comment: @FooBarUser: That's already explained in the answer. See "Older versions of `pip`…" and "And some distros…" I edited the answer to split those off into separate paragraphs to make it harder to miss; does that help?

Comment: Just trying it and it comes up looks like it's going to do it but then I get Permission denied on it trying to create the python3.3/dist-packages/PIL directory.  I am doing this on a full installion on Linux and not through a virtual player.

Comment: @confused: Most likely you need to `sudo` the install, just as you do with most system-wide install commands. (If you don't understand `sudo`, you probably need to read a Unix tutorial or ask on a site like SuperUser.)

Comment: That's exactly what the problem was.  I just happened to think about it and tried it and it worked beautifully.  Thanks for the help.